# Rusage with wait4() does not show CPU time of finished child process

Tags: c, linux, rusage

I have a simple function which creates a child process, waits for it to finish and prints CPU system and user time.

```
int PrintChildProcessTime(char **arg)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct rusage usage;

    if ((pid=fork()) == 0)
    {
        execvp(arg[0],arg);

        perror("Execvp error");
        _exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        wait4(pid, &status, 0, &usage);
        printf ("CPU time: %ld.%06ld sec user, %ld.%06ld sec system\n", usage.ru_utime.tv_sec, usage.ru_utime.tv_usec, usage.ru_stime.tv_sec, usage.ru_stime.tv_usec);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Fork error");
        _exit(2);
    }
}
```

The thing is, even when I pass `sleep 10` as `**arg` and the parent process waits for the child to finish, then it still shows 0.000000 in both system and user CPU time.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there's time spent by the child process either in user space or in the kernel space. `sleep` simply suspends the calling process and doesn't result in any CPU usage at all.

Instead make your child process do something and you'll see the CPU time.

For example, have a script called `myscript` with:

```
 #!/bin/bash

for((i=0;i<1000000;i++)); do
   echo hi >/dev/null
done
```

and execute it as the child proces which will show some CPU usage.